# The following function doesn't give any output

Tags: python, pycharm

The following function doesn't give any output. Its just showing following output in console "Process finished with exit code 0"

Python 3.x, Pycharm IDE

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
            return translation
    print(translate(input("Enter a phrase")))
```

A user Input prompt expected in the above function

Comment: Have you called the function?

Comment: your function is called translate and you are calling translation

Comment: Yes i called the function within print function in last line pl

Comment: And you probably want to call it outside the function block (the print statement)

Comment: Yep. I have even changed function name to translate.. though result is the same pl

Answer (score 2):

your syntax is wrong:

call your function outside of function block

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter a phrase")))
```

Comment: I just copied and paste on my IDE.. Output is the same, no function is giving any output. Pycharm IDE.. Any help pl